# swagger-codegen does not generate models for nested objects

Tags: python, yaml, swagger-codegen

We use swagger-codegen v2.3.0 to generate an API client in Python from a yml API spec.
In the case of nested objects, e.g.

```
definitions:
  Toplevel:
    type: object
    properties:
      id:
        type: string
      Nested:
        type: object
        properties:
          name:
            type: string
```

It would generate model classes `Toplevel` and `ToplevelNested`.

After upgrading to v2.4.18 it does not generate a model for the `Nested`, and the type of the `nested` parameter to the `Toplevel` is declared as just `object`.

Is it perhaps a change in the default behavior that can be controlled by invocation parameters? Thanks.